# Nginx configuration is catching all subdomains without a wildcard, how to fix?

Tags: nginx

My Nginx config is catching all subdomains without specifying a wildcard. I have created an special config for each subdomain, but seems that all subdomains pass trough the main domain configuration. I have discovered this by removing the subdomains configuration files from nginx.conf and watching how it still catches all the subdomains, so when I send a request to uk.domain.com, instead of Nginx catching the subdomain configuration, goes through the main domain configuration. This is causing trouble with applying mod_pagespeed individually to each of the sites and also managing the GA universal code.

The config for the main domain is this :

```
server {

        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        access_log  off;
        root /var/www/domain.com/wordpress;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name domain.com;
        if ($allow = no) {
        return 403;
        }
        if ($bad_referer) {
        return 444;
        }
         if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }






        client_body_buffer_size 124K;

        client_header_buffer_size 1k;

        client_max_body_size 100m;

        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types application/json application/x-javascript application/xml text/javascript text/plain text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml+rss;

        # Rewrites for Yoast SEO XML Sitemap
        rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
        include hhvm.conf;
        include domain.com-ps.conf;
        include multisite.conf;
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$server_name$uri/ permanent;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

         if ($bad_client) { return 403; }



        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        }
```

Why is this configuration catching all subdomains if I am not specyfing a wildcard ?

Nginx.conf config :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;

#error_log    /var/log/nginx/logs/error.log;
#error_log   /var/log/nginx/logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log   /var/log/nginx/logs/error.log  info;
#access_log  off;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}


http {

        access_log  off;
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        sendfile        on;
        tcp_nopush     on;

        #keepalive_timeout  0;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        client_body_buffer_size 124K;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;


        map $http_cf_ipcountry $allow {
        default yes;
        default yes;
        IN no;
        CN no;
        PK no;
        RU no;
        BD no;
        UA no;
}


        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types application/json application/x-javascript application/xml text/javascript text/plain text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml+rss;
        include /etc/nginx/blacklist.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/domain.com;
#       include /etc/nginx/us.domain.com;
        include /etc/nginx/uk.domain.com;
        include /etc/nginx/ca.domain.com;
        include /etc/nginx/au.domain.com;
        include /etc/nginx/anotherdomain.com;
        include /etc/nginx/refer-spam.conf;
}
```

subdomain configuration file :

```
server {

        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
#       server_name_in_redirect off;
        access_log  on;
        error_log on;
        root /var/www/elsitar.com/wordpress;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name uk.domain.com;
        if ($allow = no) {
        return 403;
        }
         if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jp$
                access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }
        client_body_buffer_size 124K;

        client_header_buffer_size 1k;

        client_max_body_size 100m;

        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

        error_page 404 /404.html;



        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types application/json application/x-javascript application/xml te$

        # Rewrites for Yoast SEO XML Sitemap
        rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_$
        include hhvm.conf;
        include uk.domain.com-ps.conf;
        include multisite.conf;
        include uk.elsitar.com-ps.conf;
        include multisite.conf;
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$server_name$uri/ permanent;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

         if ($bad_client) { return 403; }
       location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        }
}
```

HHVM config with fallback to fpm :

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 502 = @fpm;
    try_files $uri /index.php;


    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location @fpm {
  try_files $uri /index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
#  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
#  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:8000;
  fastcgi_buffers 32 16k;
}
```

Wordpress Multisite rewrites :

```
# Rewrite rules for WordPress Multi-site.
if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with a "default site config" ? What I do is to create a config file for each subdomain and for the main site ( the one I posted ) and then include each of these on the http config ( nginx.conf in my case )

Comment: There should be a sites-available and sites-enabled folder. In the sites-available folder should be a config called default. It should be then sym lined to sites-enabled. The idea is that this handles everything you don't have a config specifically for. The sites-enabled folder would be referenced from the nginx.conf file

Comment: @xavier It would help if you could post your nginx.conf, and your folder structure under /etc/nginx

Comment: I have posted the nginx.conf on an edit. As you can see, I include the other sites configuration the same way I include the main domain config. I have compiled nginx manually so there is no sites-enabled / sites-available, I think that is an Ubuntu / Debian style package implementation.

Comment: @drifter104 that paradigm only holds on debian-based installs of Nginx. By default Nginx does not config like that

Comment: Ah I did not know that. However I think I've misunderstood the question anyway. Are you saying that inside the uk.domain.com config the server_name uk.domain.com but even with that the domain.com config handles every request? or just some requests?

Comment: Exacty, that is what I am saying. Each subdomain config included has its own subdomain name only in server_name AKA  : uk.domain.com, but the request goes through the main domain config : domain.com and nginx processes the request through that. If I remove the includes, all subdomains still work, meaning that the requests are being catched at the main site config.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Can you add the uk.domain.com config too please, or any of those not working

Comment: @Drifter104 I have added the subdomain config as well as the hhvm config and also the multisite rewrites.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the order of the includes but I'm pretty sure that should make no difference. Can you try with `include /etc/nginx/domain.com;` at the bottom of the list of includes for the domains

Comment: yeah, just tested it ... it doesn't work

Comment: argh... server_name is done on exact match being the best option, so as your subdomain is the best match it should be selected. If you able to `#` the include line for the domain.com does the subdomain file then process the request?

Answer (score 1):

1.) Remove your default config

> rm -R /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*

2.) Move your Configurations into the sites-available folder

> mv /etc/nginx/*.comain.com /sites-available
>
> mv /etc/nginx/anotherdomain /sites-available

3.) Link all Configurations in the sites-enabled folder to "enable" them.

> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/anyconfig /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/anyconfig

4.) Reload Nginx

> service nginx configtest
>
> service nginx reload

Check all your Configuration for the following Parts in the listen directive:
"default_site" and "_"

Both work as an Catch all mechanismus.

**Edit nginx.conf**

remove all includes and add:
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*

Following this procedur, you have no "Wildcard" Nginx config anymore. To enable "Catch all", just create a new config, or edit a existing config and add "default_server", looks like:

> server {
>
> listen 80;
>
> listen 443 ssl default_server;
>
> ... }

BR Bernd

Comment: I have compiled nginx manually, there is not sites enabled / sites available directories. After all that only serves the purpose of including or not an specific site configuration.

Comment: hmm, strange. catch all is normaly just provided through "default_server" or "_". Can you show us:         include hhvm.conf;
        include domain.com-ps.conf;
        include multisite.conf;

Comment: I have added via edit the config you are asking for.